# is this usage of dot operator allowed (consecutive method calls instead of ? what is this usage of dot-operator called

Tags: java

the bottom member method has a consecutive use of the "." operator to call member "set" methods as a way to return an object

I haven't encountered this syntax before
is this valid Java syntax? what is this chaining called (how can I lookup such syntax usage?)?

```
public class OrderItemModel {
    private String restaurantId;
    private String restaurantName;
    private List<FoodModel> foods;
    private List<Long> numOfFoods;

    private OrderItemModel() {}
```

.
.
.

```
    public static OrderItemModel buildAdditional(ShoppingCartModel shoppingCart) {
        return new OrderItemModel().
        setRestaturantId(shoppingCart.getAdditionalRestaurantID()).
        setRestaurntName(shoppingCart.getAdditionalRestaurantName()).
        setFoods(shoppingCart.getAdditionalFoods()).
        setNumOfFoods(shoppingCart.getNumOfAdditionalFood());
    }
```

Comment: Builder pattern.

Comment: It is method chaining. It constructs a new object, calls a method on the object, calls a method what the first method returns, etc, etc

Comment: Two notes: When chaining on multiple lines like this it's customary to indent and to put the dot on at the beginning of the line to make it clear to a reader that it's a continuation of the statement, and for better or for worse standard JavaBean setters are void (not returning `this`), so this style is normally only seen in builders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible with methods like this, which return an instance of the class when they're called:

```
class Person {

    public Person setName(String a) {

        return this;
    }

    public Person setAge(int age) {

        return this;
    }

}
```

And using it like so:

```
Person person = new Person();
person.setName("abc").setAge(19);
```

The reason this is possible is you have variable `person`, you set the name using `setName` but `setName` returns an instance of that class, therefore you can call `setAge` on that instance that was returned etc. It's not called a *'dot operator'* it's just chaining method calls.